# Cannot find Table[0]

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to calculate Accounting equation by filling the results into the database; however, I tried to execute them but the error appeared

> Cannot Find DataTable[0]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     //row[6]= qty.
     //row[7] =unitval.
     //row[8]=balance.
     //row[9]=avg.
     string ccc = CCC.Properties.Settings.Default.CCCConnectionString;   
     string x = string.Empty;
     x = "Insert Into [Test$]([unitval],[balance],[avg])" 
        + "Values(@unitval,@balance,@avg)";      
     using (SqlConnection c= new SqlConnection(ccc))
     {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(x,c))
        {
           c.Open();
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();      
           //DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];               
           foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
           {
              if (Convert.ToInt32(r[7]) != 0)
              {
                 r[8] = Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) + Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@balance", r[8]));
                 r[9] = ((Convert.ToInt32(r[6]) - Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) * Convert.ToDouble(r[9])) + (Convert.ToDouble(r[7]) * Convert.ToInt32(r[6]))) / Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) + Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@avg", r[9]));
              }
              else
              {
                 r[7] = r[9];
                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@unitval", r[9]));
                 r[8] = Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) - Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@balance", r[8]));
                 r[9] = r[9];
                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@avg", r[9]));
              }                  
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              c.Close();
              label2.Text = "Done";
           }
        }
     }
  }
  catch (Exception f)
  {
     label2.Text = "Not Inserted" + "Error: " + f.Message;
  }
}
```

Here is an example of how to fill the null or 0 numbers : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZuVb.jpg. I tried to figure the problem, but i am still confused.

**UPDATED**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string ccc = CCC.Properties.Settings.Default.CCCConnectionString;

            string x = string.Empty;
            x = "Insert Into [Test$]([unitval],[balance],[avg])" 
                + "Values(@unitval,@balance,@avg)";

            using (SqlConnection c= new SqlConnection(ccc))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(x,c))
                {
                    c.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    string sql = "select * From Test$";
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, c);
                    da.Fill(ds, "Test$");
                    //DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

                    foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(r[7]) != 0)
                        {
                            r[8] = Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) + Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@balance", r[8]));
                            r[9] = ((Convert.ToInt32(r[6]) - Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) * Convert.ToDouble(r[9])) + (Convert.ToDouble(r[7]) * Convert.ToInt32(r[6]))) / Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) + Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@avg", r[9]));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            r[7] = r[9];
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@unitval", r[9]));
                            r[8] = Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) - Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@balance", r[8]));
                            r[9] = r[9];
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@avg", r[9]));
                        }

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        c.Close();
                        label2.Text = "Done";
                    }


                }

            }




        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            label2.Text = "Not Inserted" + "Error: " + f.Message;

        }



    }
```

Comment: You're creating a new `DataSet` but then not adding any tables into it: `DataSet ds = new DataSet();` Where do you expect it to get any data from?

Comment: You create a ew dataset without any configuration. Is it supposed to magically have the tables you want?

Comment: I don't understand, when you write `DataSet ds = new DataSet();` it generates empty `DataSet`. How do you think you can access it's `Tables`?

Comment: Before iterating through the tables in dataset, first fill the tables in dataset using sqldatadapter object fill method.

Comment: Thank for your replies. I understood the function of dataset but i received other error "Must Declare the scalar variable "@unitval"

Answer (score 3):

You have an issue with this line

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

You are creating dataset but not filling it with any data so how you can imagine it will have any rows??
try to fill data like this

```
string cmd="select * from some_table";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, c);
adapter.Fill(ds, "some_table");
```

**Updated Code**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string ccc = CCC.Properties.Settings.Default.CCCConnectionString;

        string x = string.Empty;
            x = "Insert Into Test$ (unitval,balance,avg)"
                + " Values(@uval,@balance,@avg)";

            using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ccc))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(x, c))
                {
                    c.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    string sql = "select * From Test$";
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, c);
                    da.Fill(ds, "Test$");
                    //DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

                    foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(r[7]) != 0)
                        {
                            r[8] = Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) + Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", r[8]);
                            r[9] = ((Convert.ToInt32(r[6]) - Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) * Convert.ToDouble(r[9])) + (Convert.ToDouble(r[7]) * Convert.ToInt32(r[6]))) / Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) + Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avg", r[9]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            r[7] = r[9];
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uval", r[9]);
                            r[8] = Convert.ToInt32(r[8]) - Convert.ToInt32(r[6]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", r[8]);
                            r[9] = r[9];
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avg", r[9]);
                        }

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        c.Close();
                        label2.Text = "Done";
                    }


                }

            }




        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            label2.Text = "Not Inserted" + "Error: " + f.Message;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your generous reply. However, i did it before and had an error, "Must Declare the scalar Variable "@unitval".

Comment: if you will paste your code here for filling dataset it would be great to help. Please note with SqlDataAdapter only sql select statement is used.

Comment: I just updated the code; as i mentioned before it worked with select only before, but it did not fill the results, so i used "Insert Into" statement to fill or fetch the results into the table.

Comment: There is an error at "Value". 
Error 1 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Unfortunately, "Must Declare the scalar Variable "@unitval", Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: this error is popping up because your parameter @unitval in insert statement and cm.parameters.add are different. may be due to case etc. i have changed the code please check it and make sure you are using correct variable names and column names

Comment: I used break-point at "c.open()", but it broke at cmd.executenonquery(). still the error scalar value. However, i add the unitval, it returns what in the row, but the error changed, at cmd.execute, to "cannot insert the value Null into column row[5]". Lol it's so logical.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  and use [Fill Method (DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to fill the data set before using the table/rows therein.